# How to move paginator block to the footer?

Tags: python, html, css, django, pagination

I have developed a django application. I added a paginator block to a webpage. It is placed on the wrong position. Instead, i want it to be placed below the list which is being shown. Actually, I am displaying group list on the page. Per page, only 5 group names will be displayed. Using pagination, i did that. But the problem is i am unable to place it in a correct position. I am attaching an image of the page.

[image: As it can be seen, page numbers are displayed at the left side instead of being shown below the group list block]

The html page for this is:

```
    {% extends "groups/group_base.html" %}
{% block pregroup %}
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="content">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h2>
            Welcome back
            <a href="{% url 'posts:for_user' username=user.username %}">@{{user.username }}</a>
        </h2>

    {% endif %}
            <h2>Groups</h2>

            <p>Welcome to the Groups Page! Select a Group with a shared interest!</p>
    </div>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'groups:create' %}" class="btn btn-md btn-fill btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Create New Group!</a>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block group_content %}

<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="list-group">
        {% for group in object_list %}
          <a class="list-group-item" href="{% url 'groups:single' slug=group.slug %}">
                 <h3 class="title list-group-item-heading">{{ group.name }}</h3>
            <div class="list-group-item-text container-fluid">
                {{ group.description_html|safe }}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <span class="badge">{{ group.members.count }}</span> member{{ group.members.count|pluralize }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <span class="badge">{{ group.posts.count }}</span> post{{ group.posts.count|pluralize }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

</div>
{% block pagination %}
{% if is_paginated %}
  <ul class="pagination" style="display:inline-block">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
      {% if page_obj.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pagination code should be inside the **col-md-8** div tag like below ::

```
 {% extends "groups/group_base.html" %}
{% block pregroup %}
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="content">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h2>
            Welcome back
            <a href="{% url 'posts:for_user' username=user.username %}">@{{user.username }}</a>
        </h2>

    {% endif %}
            <h2>Groups</h2>

            <p>Welcome to the Groups Page! Select a Group with a shared interest!</p>
    </div>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'groups:create' %}" class="btn btn-md btn-fill btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Create New Group!</a>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block group_content %}

<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="list-group">
        {% for group in object_list %}
          <a class="list-group-item" href="{% url 'groups:single' slug=group.slug %}">
                 <h3 class="title list-group-item-heading">{{ group.name }}</h3>
            <div class="list-group-item-text container-fluid">
                {{ group.description_html|safe }}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <span class="badge">{{ group.members.count }}</span> member{{ group.members.count|pluralize }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <span class="badge">{{ group.posts.count }}</span> post{{ group.posts.count|pluralize }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% block pagination %}
{% if is_paginated %}
  <ul class="pagination" style="display:inline-block">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
      {% if page_obj.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

</div>



{% endblock %}
```